# "knife node edit" fails

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I followed the Chef beginner's tutorial in
https://learnchef.opscode.com/quickstart/converge/
and 
https://learnchef.opscode.com/starter-use-cases/ntp/

I try ro add the ntp cookbook in the node's run-list.

For this, I try to run

```
knife node edit localhost
```

where localhost is the hostname, but it fails to understand the "localhost".
However, the

```
knife bootstrap localhost
```

command did understand the localhost.

What am I doing wrong?

The logs are as follows:

(`chef-repo_default_1380728124` is the name of the VM in VirtualBox)

---

```
$ knife edit node yannis-starter
ERROR: node: No such file or directory
ERROR: yannis-starter: No such file or directory

Administrator@PAVILION ~/chef-repo (master)
$ knife edit node vagrant
ERROR: node: No such file or directory
ERROR: vagrant: No such file or directory

Administrator@PAVILION ~/chef-repo (master)
$ knife edit node chef-repo_default_1380728124
ERROR: node: No such file or directory
ERROR: chef-repo_default_1380728124: No such file or directory

Administrator@PAVILION ~/chef-repo (master)
$ knife edit node localhost
ERROR: node: No such file or directory
ERROR: localhost: No such file or directory

Administrator@PAVILION ~/chef-repo (master)
$ knife cookbook upload --all
Uploading aliases        [0.1.0]
Uploading apache2        [1.7.0]
Uploading apt            [2.1.2]
Uploading magic_shell    [0.3.2]
Uploading ntp            [0.1.0]
Uploading starter        [1.0.0]
Uploaded all cookbooks.

Administrator@PAVILION ~/chef-repo (master)
$ cd ~/chef-repo

Administrator@PAVILION ~/chef-repo (master)
$ vagrant up --no-color
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[default] VirtualBox VM is already running.

Administrator@PAVILION ~/chef-repo (master)
$ knife bootstrap localhost \
>   --ssh-user vagrant \
>   --ssh-password vagrant \
>   --ssh-port 2222 \
>   --run-list "recipe[apt],recipe[aliases],recipe[apache2],recipe[ntp]" \
>   --sudo
Bootstrapping Chef on localhost
localhost Starting Chef Client, version 11.6.0[0m
localhost
localhost resolving cookbooks for run list: ["apt", "aliases", "apache2", "ntp"][0m
localhost
localhost Synchronizing Cookbooks:[0m
localhost
localhost   - apt[0m
localhost
localhost   - aliases[0m
localhost
localhost   - magic_shell[0m
localhost
localhost   - apache2[0m
localhost
localhost   - ntp[0m
localhost
localhost Compiling Cookbooks...[0m
localhost
localhost [2013-10-03T00:12:27+00:00] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for service[apache2] from prior resource (CHEF-3
694)
localhost
localhost [2013-10-03T00:12:27+00:00] WARN: Previous service[apache2]: /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/apache2/recipes/default
.rb:24:in `from_file'
localhost
localhost [2013-10-03T00:12:27+00:00] WARN: Current  service[apache2]: /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/apache2/recipes/default
.rb:221:in `from_file'
localhost
localhost Converging 48 resources[0m
localhost
localhost Recipe: apt::default[0m
localhost
localhost   * execute[apt-get-update] action run[0m
localhost  (skipped due to not_if)[0m
localhost
localhost   * execute[apt-get update] action nothing[0m
localhost  (skipped due to action :nothing)[0m
localhost
localhost   * execute[apt-get autoremove] action nothing[0m
localhost  (skipped due to action :nothing)[0m
localhost
localhost   * execute[apt-get autoclean] action nothing[0m
localhost  (skipped due to action :nothing)[0m
localhost
localhost   * package[update-notifier-common] action install[0m
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost   * execute[apt-get-update-periodic] action run[0m
localhost  (skipped due to only_if)[0m
localhost
localhost   * directory[/var/cache/local] action create[0m
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost   * directory[/var/cache/local/preseeding] action create[0m
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost Recipe: aliases::default[0m
localhost
localhost   * magic_shell_alias[h] action add[0m
localhost Recipe: <Dynamically Defined Resource>[0m
localhost
localhost   * file[/etc/profile.d/h.sh] action create[0m
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost   * file[/etc/profile.d/h.sh] action nothing[0m
localhost  (skipped due to action :nothing)[0m
localhost
localhost Recipe: aliases::default[0m
localhost
localhost   * magic_shell_alias[sites] action add[0m
localhost Recipe: <Dynamically Defined Resource>[0m
localhost
localhost   * file[/etc/profile.d/sites.sh] action create[0m
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost   * file[/etc/profile.d/sites.sh] action nothing[0m
localhost  (skipped due to action :nothing)[0m
localhost
localhost Recipe: aliases::default[0m
localhost
localhost   * magic_shell_environment[EDITOR] action add[0m
localhost Recipe: <Dynamically Defined Resource>[0m
localhost
localhost   * file[/etc/profile.d/EDITOR.sh] action create[0m
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost   * file[/etc/profile.d/EDITOR.sh] action nothing[0m
localhost  (skipped due to action :nothing)[0m
localhost
localhost Recipe: apache2::default[0m
localhost
localhost   * package[apache2] action install[0m
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost   * service[apache2] action enable[0m
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost   * directory[/etc/apache2/ssl] action create[0m
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost   * directory[/etc/apache2/conf.d] action create[0m
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost   * directory[/var/cache/apache2] action create[0m
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost   * template[/etc/sysconfig/httpd] action create[0m
localhost  (skipped due to only_if)[0m
localhost
localhost   * template[apache2.conf] action create[0m
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost   * template[apache2-conf-security] action create[0m
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost   * template[apache2-conf-charset] action create[0m
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost   * template[/etc/apache2/ports.conf] action create[0m
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost   * template[/etc/apache2/sites-available/default] action create[0m
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost Recipe: apache2::mod_status[0m
localhost
localhost   * template[/etc/apache2/mods-available/status.conf] action create[0m
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost   * execute[a2enmod status] action run[0m
localhost  (skipped due to not_if)[0m
localhost
localhost Recipe: apache2::mod_alias[0m
localhost
localhost   * template[/etc/apache2/mods-available/alias.conf] action create[0m
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost   * execute[a2enmod alias] action run[0m
localhost  (skipped due to not_if)[0m
localhost
localhost Recipe: apache2::mod_auth_basic[0m
localhost
localhost   * execute[a2enmod auth_basic] action run[0m
localhost  (skipped due to not_if)[0m
localhost
localhost Recipe: apache2::mod_authn_file[0m
localhost
localhost   * execute[a2enmod authn_file] action run[0m
localhost  (skipped due to not_if)[0m
localhost
localhost Recipe: apache2::mod_authz_default[0m
localhost
localhost   * execute[a2enmod authz_default] action run[0m
localhost  (skipped due to not_if)[0m
localhost
localhost Recipe: apache2::mod_authz_groupfile[0m
localhost
localhost   * execute[a2enmod authz_groupfile] action run[0m
localhost  (skipped due to not_if)[0m
localhost
localhost Recipe: apache2::mod_authz_host[0m
localhost
localhost   * execute[a2enmod authz_host] action run[0m
localhost  (skipped due to not_if)[0m
localhost
localhost Recipe: apache2::mod_authz_user[0m
localhost
localhost   * execute[a2enmod authz_user] action run[0m
localhost  (skipped due to not_if)[0m
localhost
localhost Recipe: apache2::mod_autoindex[0m
localhost
localhost   * template[/etc/apache2/mods-available/autoindex.conf] action create[0m
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost   * execute[a2enmod autoindex] action run[0m
localhost  (skipped due to not_if)[0m
localhost
localhost Recipe: apache2::mod_dir[0m
localhost
localhost   * template[/etc/apache2/mods-available/dir.conf] action create[0m
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost   * execute[a2enmod dir] action run[0m
localhost  (skipped due to not_if)[0m
localhost
localhost Recipe: apache2::mod_env[0m
localhost
localhost   * execute[a2enmod env] action run[0m
localhost  (skipped due to not_if)[0m
localhost
localhost Recipe: apache2::mod_mime[0m
localhost
localhost   * template[/etc/apache2/mods-available/mime.conf] action create[0m
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost   * execute[a2enmod mime] action run[0m
localhost  (skipped due to not_if)[0m
localhost
localhost Recipe: apache2::mod_negotiation[0m
localhost
localhost   * template[/etc/apache2/mods-available/negotiation.conf] action create[0m
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost   * execute[a2enmod negotiation] action run[0m
localhost  (skipped due to not_if)[0m
localhost
localhost Recipe: apache2::mod_setenvif[0m
localhost
localhost   * template[/etc/apache2/mods-available/setenvif.conf] action create[0m
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost   * execute[a2enmod setenvif] action run[0m
localhost  (skipped due to not_if)[0m
localhost
localhost Recipe: apache2::default[0m
localhost
localhost   * execute[a2dissite default] action run[0m
localhost  (skipped due to only_if)[0m
localhost
localhost   * service[apache2] action start[0m
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost Recipe: ntp::default[0m
localhost
localhost   * package[ntp] action install[0m
localhost [32m
localhost
localhost     - install version 1:4.2.6.p3+dfsg-1ubuntu3.1 of package ntp[0m
localhost
localhost [0m
localhost
localhost   * template[/etc/ntp.conf] action create[0m
localhost [32m
localhost
localhost     - update content in file /etc/ntp.conf from 4eb9a0 to f4bd23[0m
localhost [37m
localhost
localhost         --- /etc/ntp.conf
localhost
localhost 2012-06-05 20:12:22.000000000 +0000[0m
localhost [37m
localhost
localhost         +++ /tmp/chef-rendered-template20131003-3352-zv5vk7
localhost
localhost 2013-10-03 00:12:32.846736126 +0000[0m
localhost [37m
localhost
localhost         @@ -1,55 +1,12 @@[0m
localhost [37m
localhost
localhost         -# /etc/ntp.conf, configuration for ntpd; see ntp.conf(5) for help[0m
localhost [37m
localhost
localhost         -[0m
localhost [37m
localhost
localhost         -driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift[0m
localhost [37m
localhost
localhost         -[0m
localhost [37m
localhost
localhost         -[0m
localhost [37m
localhost
localhost         -# Enable this if you want statistics to be logged.[0m
localhost [37m
localhost
localhost         -#statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/[0m
localhost [37m
localhost
localhost         -[0m
localhost [37m
localhost
localhost         -statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats[0m
localhost [37m
localhost
localhost         -filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable[0m
localhost [37m
localhost
localhost         -filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable[0m
localhost [37m
localhost
localhost         -filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable[0m
localhost [37m
localhost
localhost         -[0m
localhost [37m
localhost
localhost         -# Specify one or more NTP servers.[0m
localhost [37m
localhost
localhost         -[0m
localhost [37m
localhost
localhost         -# Use servers from the NTP Pool Project. Approved by Ubuntu Technical Board[0m
localhost [37m
localhost
localhost         -# on 2011-02-08 (LP: #104525). See http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html for[0m
localhost [37m
localhost
localhost         -# more information.[0m
localhost [37m
localhost
localhost         -server 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org[0m
localhost [37m
localhost
localhost         -server 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org[0m[37m
localhost         -server 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org[0m[37m
localhost         -server 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org[0m[37m
localhost
localhost         -[0m[37m
localhost
localhost         -# Use Ubuntu's ntp server as a fallback.[0m[37m
localhost
localhost         -server ntp.ubuntu.com[0m[37m
localhost         -[0m[37m
localhost
localhost         -# Access control configuration; see /usr/share/doc/ntp-doc/html/accopt.html for[0m[37m
localhost         -# details.  The web page <http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/AccessRestrictions>[0m[37m
localhost         -# might also be helpful.[0m[37m
localhost         -#[0m[37m
localhost         -# Note that "restrict" applies to both servers and clients, so a configuration[0m[37m
localhost         -# that might be intended to block requests from certain clients could also end[0m[37m
localhost         -# up blocking replies from your own upstream servers.[0m[37m
localhost         -[0m[37m
localhost         -# By default, exchange time with everybody, but don't allow configuration.[0m[37m
localhost
localhost         -restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery[0m[37m
localhost
localhost         -restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery[0m[37m
localhost         -[0m[37m
localhost
localhost         -# Local users may interrogate the ntp server more closely.[0m[37m
localhost
localhost         -restrict 127.0.0.1[0m[37m
localhost         -restrict ::1[0m[37m
localhost
localhost         -[0m[37m
localhost
localhost         -# Clients from this (example!) subnet have unlimited access, but only if[0m[37m
localhost
localhost         -# cryptographically authenticated.[0m[37m
localhost
localhost         -#restrict 192.168.123.0 mask 255.255.255.0 notrust[0m[37m
localhost         -[0m[37m
localhost         -[0m[37m
localhost         -# If you want to provide time to your local subnet, change the next line.[0m[37m
localhost         -# (Again, the address is an example only.)[0m[37m
localhost         -#broadcast 192.168.123.255[0m[37m
localhost
localhost         -[0m[37m
localhost         -# If you want to listen to time broadcasts on your local subnet, de-comment the[0m[37m
localhost
localhost         -# next lines.  Please do this only if you trust everybody on the network![0m[37m
localhost         -#disable auth[0m[37m
localhost
localhost         -#broadcastclient[0m[37m
[0m[37m         +# This file was generated by Chef for 'yannis-starter'.
localhost
[0m[37m         +# Do NOT edit this file by hand!
[0m[37m         +
localhost
[0m[37m         +restrict default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
localhost
[0m[37m         +restrict -6 default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
localhost
[0m[37m         +restrict 127.0.0.1
localhost
[0m[37m         +restrict -6 ::1
localhost
[0m[37m         +server '0.pool.ntp.org'
[0m[37m         +server  127.127.1.0     # local clock
[0m[37m         +driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
[0m[37m         +keys /etc/ntp/keys
[0mlhost         +
localhost [0m
localhost
localhost   * service[ntp] action enable[0m
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost   * service[ntp] action start[0m
localhost  (up to date)[0m
localhost
localhost   * service[ntp] action restart[0m
localhost [32m
localhost
localhost     - restart service service[ntp][0m
localhost
localhost [0m
localhost
localhost Chef Client finished, 3 resources updated[0m
localhost

Administrator@PAVILION ~/chef-repo (master)
$ knife node edit localhost
ERROR: The object you are looking for could not be found
Response: node 'localhost' not found

Administrator@PAVILION ~/chef-repo (master)
$ vagrant ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.5.0-23-generic i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

Last login: Thu Oct  3 00:12:18 2013 from 10.0.2.2
vagrant@yannis-starter:~$ hostname
yannis-starter
vagrant@yannis-starter:~$ ping yannis-starter
PING yannis-starter (127.0.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from yannis-starter (127.0.1.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.032 ms
64 bytes from yannis-starter (127.0.1.1): icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.027 ms
64 bytes from yannis-starter (127.0.1.1): icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.032 ms

--- yannis-starter ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.027/0.030/0.032/0.005 ms
vagrant@yannis-starter:~$ exit
logout
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.

Administrator@PAVILION ~/chef-repo (master)
$ ping yannis-starter
Ping request could not find host yannis-starter. Please check the name and try again.

Administrator@PAVILION ~/chef-repo (master)
$ vagrant ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.5.0-23-generic i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

Last login: Thu Oct  3 00:20:06 2013 from 10.0.2.2
vagrant@yannis-starter:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:d0:18:0b
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fed0:180b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:27212 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14893 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:32931491 (32.9 MB)  TX bytes:1452344 (1.4 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:504 (504.0 B)  TX bytes:504 (504.0 B)

vagrant@yannis-starter:~$ exit
logout
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.

Administrator@PAVILION ~/chef-repo (master)
```

Comment: provide the output/error of command `knife node edit localhost`

Comment: @slayedbylucifer: Sorry for the late response, I did not see the comment, I'm new to this forum. The output that you requested is inside the big log thatI submitted but I admit it is difficult to see. I paste it here: `$ knife node edit localhost
ERROR: The object you are looking for could not be found
Response: node 'localhost' not found`

Comment: Also, I apologize for the mistake in my initial logs. The correct was `knife node edit localhost` and not `knife edit node localhost`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`knife bootstrap` takes a hostname or IP address as a parameter. In your case, `localhost` will resolve to `127.0.0.1` and knife will bootstrap your local machine.

`knife node edit`, on the other hand, takes a node's `name` for its parameter.

If you haven't set the `name` attribute during bootstrap, it will default to your machine's hostname -- you can get it by issuing `hostname` on the shell, or just use `knife node edit $(hostname)`.

If that doesn't work, try doing a search on the Chef server for all your nodes with `knife search 'name:*'`. Find your local host there and use its `name` with `knife node edit`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. `knife node edit $(hostname)` did not help because it tried to talk again to the Chef workstation (=localhost) and not to the node. But by searching with `knife search 'name:*'` I found the node name. I post the solution bellow.

Answer (score 0):

@cbl: Thank you for your help. `knife node edit $(hostname)` did not help because it tried to talk again to the Chef workstation (=localhost) and not to the node. But by searching with `knife search 'name:*'` I found the node name. The solution is bellow:

---

```
$ echo $(hostname)
pavilion

Administrator@PAVILION ~/chef-repo (master)
$ knife node edit $(hostname)
ERROR: The object you are looking for could not be found
Response: node 'pavilion' not found

Administrator@PAVILION ~/chef-repo (master)
$ knife search 'name:*'
1 items found

Node Name:   yannis-starter
Environment: _default
FQDN:        yannis-starter
IP:          10.0.2.15
Run List:    recipe[apt], recipe[aliases], recipe[apache2], recipe[ntp]
Roles:
Recipes:     apt, aliases, apache2, ntp
Platform:    ubuntu 12.04
Tags:


Administrator@PAVILION ~/chef-repo (master)
$ knife node edit yannis-starter
Node not updated, skipping node save

Administrator@PAVILION ~/chef-repo (master)
$
```